# No drivers found in any of my devices

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have just formatted my PC, and now my drivers are not installed. I have tried plugging them out, restarting and plugging them back in, but nothing happened. Here’s a pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOOSZ.jpg

Comment: The OS isn’t responsible for all drivers. You need to ascertain drivers manually.

Comment: Can’t download anything when my ethernet driver is not installed

Comment: not sure what you’re asking for then. Why don’t you, I don’t know, use another PC with network (or an Android phone) to download the Ethernet driver for the motherboard and copy over? Doesn’t seem too hard?

Comment: Did that, but the USB Controller driver isn’t installed too so I can’t use the USB

Comment: Jesus man. So not USB boot devices such as FalconBoot?

Comment: Can’t download it, no ethernet driver, and can’t import it through a USB because no USB drivers

Answer (score 1):

You need to download drivers form your motherboard's manufacturer's website and install them manually.

Edit:
Possible soultions if there's no internet connection:

- use phone with USB tethering to get Internet connection
- use LiveCD (eg. Linux) to boot the computer, mount Windows partition, then download the drivers and reboot
- download the drivers on another computer and copy them to USB drive or burn them to CD or DVD, then use the USB drive/CD/DVD

Comment: Can’t download any drivers if my ethernet driver isn’t installed

Comment: I had the exact same situation at my work computer once. I plugged my phone via USB cable, enabled USB internet sharing on the phone and then downloaded the drivers using my phone's internet connection.

Comment: I have tried using a USB flash drive to install my ethernet controller driver, but my USB controller driver isn’t installed so I can’t use my USB

Comment: Then the only option would be to boot from LiveCD of some sort (ie. Ubuntu), mount your Windows partition, then use the LiveCD to download drivers onto your Windows partition, reboot to Windows and then install drivers.

Comment: Can I download Realtek drivers and the like on an empty CD and import it?

Comment: If you meand download them on another computer and burn them on a CD, then yes.